# Eclipse Format Double Angle Brackets etc as XML Tags

Tags: xml, eclipse

Is there a way to have the Eclipse Editor indent the following tags as it would regular XML tags?

```
<<tag>><</tag>>
<#tag></#tag>
<$tag></$tag>
```

Specifically, I would like:

```
<<tag>><#tag><$tag>content</$tag></#tag><</tag>>
```

to format as:

```
<<tag>>
  <#tag>
    <$tag>content</$tag>
  </#tag>
<</tag>>
```

or something similar.  Currently, I get:

```
<
<tag>><#tag><$tag>content</$tag></#tag><</tag>
>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: None of those are valid XML syntax. Don't expect XML tools to handle them.

Comment: I realize this is out of the ordinary.  I'm looking for a hack here.  Thanks.

Comment: Best hack I can suggest: Write a preprocessor that converts this mess into standard XML.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I have that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It won't accept be accepted as well-formed XML syntax.

Comment: Is there really no way to accomplish this?  I don't necessarily need to use the XML Editor.  Thanks.

Comment: Accepting this as (unfortunately for me) it appears to be correct.